# bash: Script arguments ${1} interfering with xargs' ${1} inside script

Tags: bash

Long story short, I have a script chunk that looks like this:

```
cd ${1} # via command-line argument
find . -name "output*.txt" | xargs cat ${1} | grep -v ${filter} > temp.txt
```

I essentially got to this point buy building the `find ...` line in the command line, then pasting it into my script, then adding the `cd` command to make it easy to reuse this script in a wrapper that will run this script on a large set of directories. Anyway ...

The problem is that `cd` and `xargs` use the same `${1}` variable, which sort of makese

I know that I can drop the `${1}` argument from `xargs`, and I can probably rewrite the `find` command to not need `xargs` at all, but my question remains:

Is there a way to "reset" `${1}` after I use it for `cd` so that `xargs` doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with a version of `xargs` that uses `${1}` as a default replacement string, but the following should work:

```
find . -name "output*.txt" | xargs -I '{}' cat '{}' | grep -v ${filter} > temp.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of find + xargs suffers from The separator problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#Separator_problem

Here is a solution that does not have that problem. It uses GNU Parallel:

```
find . -name "output*.txt" |
  parallel cat {} |
  grep -v ${filter} > temp.txt
```

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 0):

the utility xargs is just to manage the number of arguments and there braces act as a placeholder for the arguments or filename {}.

i did simulate the wrapper you have and had the same issue the pathname passed as ${1} to my function was picked up by xargs ...... but this is how shell works , actually the shell would just substitute/expand all the variables and stuff to make the commands complete before execution

the utility arnt coded to take care of this by themselves , they just dont do that ...... 
example  :

```
echo * ;
```

here the shell would expand * and replace it with all the filenames in the current directory and pass them to the echo utility as argument @ before execution of the command echo *

likewise in your case the shell is expanding the ${1} to the pathname value you had passed before executing the command ..... thats why you got what you had.

Solution : you could just use the braces (empty of course) or better just drop them ....... it works fine for me .....

```
find . -iname "*${filename}*" | xargs ls -l | more commands ....;
```

hope this helps .